# Creating a persistent array

Tags: arrays, swift, mutable, persistent

Creating an app with a timer function. I need to record (persistently) the date and elasped time each time the user stops the timer. And a second 'page' of the app will display these in a scrollable table. Will need to record up to 10,000 entries. Would I start with NSMutableArray? And then add(_:)? Just need basic steering in the correct direction, before I get too deep along a wrong path.

Comment: Array , append for swift , coredata for storage

Comment: Do not use `NS[Mutable]Array` and similar collection classes in Swift. Use Swift collections.